# How long before I can re-register my domain at another registrar after my registrar cancelled my account and deleted my domain?

Tags: domain-registration, whois

I got the problem with my domain with 1&1. They canceled my account without any notice. Then I checked status of my domain on whois.

```
WHOIS Server: whois.1und1.de
Referral URL: http://1und1.de
Updated Date: 2016-03-18T00:05:09.0Z
Creation Date: 2016-03-02T17:33:21.0Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2017-03-02T23:59:59.0Z
Sponsoring Registrar: 1&1 Internet SE (TLDs)
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 83
Domain Status: pendingDelete https//icann.org/epp#pendingDelete
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https//icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: redemptionPeriod https//icann.org/epp#redemptionPeriod
```

So do you know when I can re-register my domain in other Provider? 
1&1 support told me 5,6 days but now is 7 days.

Comment: Related: [How do you calculate exacty when a domain in pending delete status will become available?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/64644/how-do-you-calculate-exacty-when-a-domain-in-pending-delete-status-will-become-a)

Answer (score 3):

Your domain is currently in `pendingDelete` + `redemptionPeriod` state. You can learn more about these state at the [ICANN site](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en#pendingDelete):

> **pendingDelete**
>
> This status code may be mixed with redemptionPeriod or pendingRestore. In such case, depending on the status (i.e. redemptionPeriod or pendingRestore) set in the domain name, the corresponding description presented above applies. If this status is not combined with the redemptionPeriod or pendingRestore status, the pendingDelete status code indicates that your domain has been in redemptionPeriod status for 30 days and you have not restored it within that 30-day period. Your domain will remain in this status for several days, after which time your domain will be purged and dropped from the registry database.
>
> Once deletion occurs, the domain is available for re-registration in accordance with the registry's policies.

In your case, the domain is still in `redemptionPeriod`. The `redemptionPeriod` generally lasts 30 days.

> This status code indicates that your registrar has asked the registry to delete your domain. Your domain will be held in this status for 30 days. After five calendar days following the end of the redemptionPeriod, your domain is purged from the registry database and becomes available for registration.

So, in practice, you need to wait 30 days since the domain entered `redemptionPeriod`, plus approximately 5 days for the `pendingDelete`.