# What time do .com domains drop?

Tags: domains

What time, EST, do .com domains get deleted, and available for registration by someone else? I believe it's in the range of 1 hour.

I want to hop on and register one manually without paying for backorder fees.

Is it 2-3 PM?

Comment: See also: [How do you calculate exacty when a domain in pending delete status will become available?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/64644/how-do-you-calculate-exacty-when-a-domain-in-pending-delete-status-will-become-a)

Comment: This is a mostly hopeless endeavour: you will never be fast enough competing againts highly tuned robots participating in drop catching activities. Also, your competent registrar should be able to tell you when do .COM deletes happen during the day.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific time that unpaid domains become de-registered. The process is run in batches multiple times a day and there is no real way to monitor for when it does drop except by rerunning the DNS check to see if the domain is available or backordered several times until you see it come up as available.

Comment: 1) Verisign (as we are talking about .COM specifically here) does one batch per day, from their documentation and 2) the DNS is not a good way to find out if a domain name is available or not since a domain name can be registered without any nameserver, or be put into `clientHold` status, which means it will not get published at all. Also you depend on registry nameservers update frequency (should be near real-time here normally, but you can not depend on that), and you have to be careful how you do your DNS queries.